# Does food in your owned houses replenish itself? Can I get it to do that?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do I need to get a maid? And how do I get one?  My housecarl Lydia doesn't replenish my food.  I see all these videos where they always have food layed out but I know they've been there before and taken it.  Mine however has never come back.

I just bought a house in Solitude and would like my food to replenish as I think they have done for others that play but I don't know how it's done.

Comment: There is another explanation for there being videos where houses still have food lying around - they may simply not have taking it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all of the consumables replenish, but it takes several days. In my own experience I'm thinking more of potion ingredients, even when picked and laid out on tables. However I do recall as well that the ale in my room at the College of Winterhold would replenish when I returned from travels. I believe it takes at least 4 game days.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think everything replenishes but food in your own home.  If you live at the college or any other public housing it will.